# Resetting a timer upon timeLeft = 0

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I've been trying for the better part of three days to create a quiz-like website, with a timer to encourage the user to hurry up and submit their answers. It's a very simple program, nothing special, but I'm having a great whacking issue with the timer. The timer, when it runs out, is supposed to redirect the person to the start of the page with a message "You took too long! Hurry up there will ya?". It will show the message, but the text will not change from "Finished". For reference, here is the code

HTML

```html
<body onLoad="initialize()">
  <div id="lightbox" onclick="closeLightBox()">
  <div id="message"></div>
  </div>
    <div id="countdown"></div>
```

Javascript

```js
var currentQuestion = 0;
var score = 0;

//Timer
var timeleft = 25;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0 || currentQuestion == 10){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
    message = "You took too long! Hurry up there will ya?";
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
      document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display="block";
        currentQuestion = 0;
        score = 0;
        timeleft = 25;  
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score + " / " + questions.length;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  }
  timeleft -= 1
}, 1000); //End Timer
```

I'm relatively new to this all, so if I've done something wrong please do let me know

Comment: May you condense your example down to only the parts related to the timer and the message?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That better?

Comment: It helps us provide an answer? Yes, _much_ better.

Comment: I converted the example to a snippet (adding some missing variables), and everything seems to be working well. May you further explain the issue you're seeing? (this looks fine!)

Comment: For reference, I added the wrapping `initialize` function, `var questions = [];`, and `<div id="score"></div>`. _Everything else_ is the same.

Comment: Welcome!
You told it to say "Finished" because no time left...
What do you mean "the text will not change from \"Finished\""?
To what?

Comment: @evolutionxbox You should NEVER add code to a question because for all you know the code you added is different that what the OP is using. It's better to ask the OP to add it.

Comment: @iAmOren I would like it to return from "Finished" back to a timer that will reset. Basically as if the page was reloaded

Comment: @ScottMarcus apologies. I've done this before (my mistake). Should it be rolled back?

Comment: Don't clear the interval?  Try it, and tell me what you think.

Comment: Perhaps, split: if time left = 0, done,
if time left < say, 10, message hurry up,
only clear the times if time left is zero.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, you really should.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, if a poster(OP/answerer) gives me the OK to edit the post per my suggestion, how should I do it so not to get yelled at/lose reputation?  (Not savvy enough to edit themselves, lazy, or - whatever other reason)

Comment: @iAmOren Holy smokes you're a hero. I didn't know setInterval was even a code

Comment: Glad to help! :)
What do you mean: "I didn't know setInterval was even a code"?!?

Comment: @iAmOren Lol! I've been coding for maybe about two weeks now, so I don't know much! My main skill lies in HTML and CSS, but I've never coded Javascript

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: @iAmOrden Don't ask for permission to edit their code. Ask them to do it.

Comment: Good luck on your coding adventure!
May I suggest: practice what you learn until you know it well, only then look for alternatives.
For example: `x=x+1` => `x++`, `array=[1,2,3];` + `for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) console.log(array[0]);` => + `array.forEach((item)=>console.log(item))`, etc.

Comment: @ScottMarcus rolled back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one test, which assumes that the time ran out and you didn't answer properly. You need another condition that checks for time running out and you did answer properly.

I've also moved some things around in both your HTML and your JavaScript. See the comments for details.

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="lightbox" onclick="closeLightBox()">
    <div id="message"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="countdown"></div>
  <div id="score"></div>
  
  
  <!-- Placing your script just prior to the closing body tag,
       eliminates the need for a body.onload event handler. -->
  <script>
      // Get the references to the elements you'll use over and over
      // just once
      let countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
      let message = document.getElementById("message");
      let lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox");
      let scoreArea = document.getElementById("score");
    
      var currentQuestion = 0;
      var score = 0;
      var questions = [];

      //Timer
      var timeleft = 2;
      var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
        countdown.textContent = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
        if (timeleft <= 0 && currentQuestion == 0) {
          clearInterval(downloadTimer);
          // Don't use .innerHTML when the string you are working with doesn't
          // contain any HTML as .innerHTML has security and performance impplications.
          // Use .textContent for plain strings.
          message.textContent = "You took too long! Hurry up there will ya?";
          lightbox.classList.remove("hidden");
          currentQuestion = 0;
          score = 0;
          timeleft = 25;
       } else if(timeleft <= 0) {
         scoreArea.textContent = score + " / " + questions.length;
         countdown.textContent = "Finished";       
       }
       timeleft -= 1;
      }, 1000); //End Timer



  </script>
</body>
```